# The name 'AccountPicker' does not exists in the current context - Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to learn how to use `AccountPicker` functionality in my `Xamarin`. `Android` application and can't figure out which library I must to install that contains this feature.

`Android` documentation for this can be found here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker

The application is developing under `28 API` Level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AccountPicker` class is in the `Android.Gms.Common` namespace and that is available via the nuget package `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement`:

Note: Typically `Basement` is installed as a dependency of one of the other `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.*` packages (Maps/Places/Tasks/...) but you can install it and it will add all of the Xamarin.Android.Support.* dependancies...

re: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement

Example; request account:

```
~~~
var intent = Android.Gms.Common.AccountPicker.NewChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[] { "com.google" }, false, null, null, null, null);
StartActivityForResult(intent, 99);
~~~
```

Receive account:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == 99 && resultCode == Result.Ok)
    {
        var accountName = data.GetStringExtra(AccountManager.KeyAccountName);
        Log.Debug("SO", accountName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @SushiHangover for such quick answer